# Is it safe to increase an iterator inside when using it as an argument?

Tags: c++, iterator

Currently I'm trying to erase a sequence of iterators from a set, however GCC's standard library seems to be broken because std::set::erase(iterator) should return the an iterator (next iterator), however in GCC it returns void (which is standard?)

Anyways I want to write:

```
myIter = mySet.erase(myIter);
```

But GCC doesn't like it...
So Is it safe to write this instead?

```
mySet.erase(myIter++);
```

Edit: And yes I'm checking against mySet.end();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no problem with

```
mySet.erase(myIter++);
```

The order of operation is well-defined: myIter is copied into myTempIter, myIter is incremented, and myTempIter is then given to the erase method.

**For Greg and Mark**: no, there is no way operator++ can perform operations after the call to erase. By definition, erase() is called after operator++ has returned.

Comment: What you say is true only because the operator++ has been redefined by the classes. For PODs, the operator is actually called after the line!

Comment: Yes, it is an interesting remark. And the whole point is that the order of operations is irrelevant for POD types, since incrementation is always well-defined. 
Well you can always imagine strange cases where the method has some access to a reference to the POD-variable, but that is not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

First, reread the standard and you'll see that the prototype of the set::erase method is:

```
void erase(iterator position);
```

However, the associative containers in the STL are "stable", as erasing an element do not affect the iterators on the other elements. This means that the following line is valid:

```
iterator to_erase = myIter++;
mySet.erase(to_erase);
// Now myIter is still on the next element
```

Comment: Special thanks for remembering about the fact that sets don't have random access iterators!